# Hive applications are lazy to start

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

Hive(TEZ) queries are starting in lazy fashion on YARN.

We are running Hive queries on Tez engine. As soon as we submit the queries, we are able to see the status as RUNNING, but the actual job is not starting until 10 to 15 mins.

I am not very sure what code have to present to understand the problem as Hive, Tez and YARN consists lot of configurations. Please let me know in case any configurations required for further investigation on my issue.

The expected scenario is, looking to execute the query as soon as submitted.

Comment: how do you run your queries, beeline?

Comment: No we use HortonWorks Hive ODBC Driver.